# GeoServer Image Mosaic - format date/time for TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI in indexer.xml

Tags: geoserver, netcdf, image-mosaic

I'm trying to build mosaics from NetCDF files using the indexer.xml file instead of the *.properties files so we can take advantage of the NetCDF auxiliary file. (Using GeoServer 2.14.2 btw)

My typical filenames look like: `filename_201903031503.nc`

And using the old properties files my timeregex.properties is:

```
regex=[0-9]{12},format=yyyyMMddhhmm
```

However I can't figure out how to pass the format parameter when using the indexer.xml file, I started with the following collector configuration:

```
<collectors>
  <collector name="timeFrameCollector">
    <value>format=yyyyMMddHHmm,regex=[0-9]{12}</value>
    <spi>TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI</spi>
    <mapped>time</mapped>
  </collector>
</collectors>
```

As suggested on the following page: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/ImageMosaic-indexer-xml-time-domain-custom-dimensions-td5144486.html

Unfortunately that gives me a `Failed to create reader from file:data/supplier/product` error.

As a temporary solution I can rename the files to this: `filename_20190303T150300Z.nc`

Then the following XML works:

```
<collectors>
  <collector name="timeFrameCollector">
    <value>[0-9]{8}T[0-9]{6}Z</value>
    <spi>TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI</spi>
    <mapped>time</mapped>
  </collector>
</collectors>
```

I'd really like to avoid renaming the files, they are supplied to us and I'd prefer to do zero/minimal processing. Is there a way to pass the date/time format to the collector using the indexer.xml file?

Comment: can you turn logging up to GeoTools debug and run the first one again - you should see a better error message in the log then

Comment: @IanTurton resolved the issue, the string for value has to be `regex=[0-9]{12},format=yyyyMMddhhmm` not `format=yyyyMMddhhmm,regex=[0-9]{12}`.Thanks for suggestion on turning the logging level up, resolved this issue and another related to recreating ImageMosaics that already have a schema in the index database.

Comment: Please add that as an answer for future readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ian Turon suggested in his comment, turning on a higher level of logging identified the issue.

In this case the string used in the value parameter must be `regex=[0-9]{12},format=yyyyMMddhhmm` not `format=yyyyMMddhhmm,regex=[0-9]{12}` as shown in the example [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/ImageMosaic-indexer-xml-time-domain-custom-dimensions-td5144486.html).